# Order list by specific value within in list item

Tags: php, html, list, sorting

I would like to order my unordered list by a specific value inside my list items. I generate my list with a loop.

My looped list item looks like this. The value `<?php echo $nyslutdatum; ?>` is the one I wish my list to be ordered by (displayed twice because two cases of loop conditions)

```
<li>
    <div id="kursprogram-kurstillfalle-kurs">

        <?php the_title(); ?>

    </div>

    <div id="kursprogram-kurstillfalle-ort">

        <?php the_sub_field('ort'); ?>

    </div>

    <div id="kursprogram-kurstillfalle-datum">

        <?php if(get_sub_field('startdatum') != '') { ?>

            <?php echo $nystartdatum; ?> - <?php echo $nyslutdatum; ?>

        <?php } else { ?>

            <?php echo $nyslutdatum; ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php if(get_sub_field('slutdatum_2') != '') { ?>

        <br />

            <?php echo $nystartdatum_2; ?> - <?php echo $nyslutdatum_2; ?>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>

    <div id="kursprogram-kurstillfalle-notis">

        <?php the_sub_field('notis') ?>

    </div>

    <div class="clearboth" />

</li>
```

Comment: The important part, the source you are looping, seems to be missing from your code example. Can you add it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, use the php function "usort".

The following will sort $array from highest to lowest "sales".

```
$array = array(
  array('sales'=> 10, 'views'=> 200),
  array('sales'=> 3,  'views'=> 100),
  array('sales'=> 13, 'views'=> 500)
);

usort($array,function($a,$b){
  if( $a['sales'] == $b['sales'] ){
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a['sales'] > $b['sales']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

[PHP usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)